# Flanneld: error registering network: cannot finding network with management IP

Tags: go, kubernetes, flannel, flanneld

I'm setting up a mixed-mode kubernetes cluster (CentOS7 master, WS2019 worker) using Flannel in overlay (VXLAN) mode. I've gotten through the [Microsoft Kubernetes for Windows Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/joining-windows-workers?tabs=ManagementIP) but when I kick off start.ps1 I'm stuck in the "Waiting for the Network to be created" loop referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/common-problems#after-launching-startps1-flanneld-is-stuck-in-waiting-for-the-network-to-be-created). Launching flanneld directly per their instructions, I get the following error:

> E0306 16:43:21.218797     2576 main.go:289] Error registering network: Cannot find network with Management IP [IPAddrofWorkerNIC].

The IP referenced is the main IP of the worker on the "Ethernet" NIC as called per the `--iface` argument to flanneld.

The master and worker are both Hyper-v VMs off of a Win10 1809 box with MAC spoofing enabled. I confirmed that 6433/tcp, 10250/tcp, 4096/udp, and 4789/udp are opened in firewalld of the master. I also tried again after disabling firewalld, with no change, so I don't think the issue is on the master side.

I tried digging through the [flanneld Go code](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/main.go) at the referenced line 289 for clues but I'm not familiar with Go and had to concede defeat.

Any ideas why I would be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I didn't read the requirements closely enough. Flannel VXLAN on Windows isn't supported until Kubernetes 1.14 which will release March 25.

```
Overlay networking: use Flannel in vxlan mode to configure a virtual overlay network

-     requires either Windows Server 2019 with KB4482887 installed or Windows Server vNext Insider Preview Build 18317+
-     requires Kubernetes v1.14 (or above) with WinOverlay feature gate enabled
-     requires Flannel v0.11.0 (or above)
```

Answer (score 0):

When specifying parameters for `./start.ps1`

```
.\start.ps1 -ManagementIP 10.0.xxx.xxx [...]
```

I put there IP of Kubernetes API server, instead of IP of the new Windows node, as `-ManagementIP`.

Reruning `start.ps1` with correct value resolved my problem.